# How to start web Job on azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am starting Preprocessor job on Azure but Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds after process goes to restart pending how to start and see the output.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If it's in a Pending Restart loop, then there is probably a problem with your code.  Is this new code or has it been running successfully before now?

Comment: FirstApp working good. and same code applied on preprocessor..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's usually a sign that you are running as a Continuous WebJob something that is meant to be a Triggered WebJob. Continuous is only for processes that have a forever loop looking for work, and that never normally terminate.

Comment: Thanks.. David. I need some help... Regarding How to pass parameter to preprocessor .. my parameter is "-t 1" "-s" . I am not getting any solution...

Comment: https://smcsmsmockdmzstager.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/Preprocessor/run?arguments={-t 1,-s} ... This is URL

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at SMS.Data.DataClassesDataContext..ctor()
 at SMS.Data.BatchItemType.Get(TextSendingType textSendingType)
at SMS.SBT.Preprocessor.Program.Main(String[] args)
Status changed to Failed
 Job failed due to exit code -1073741819